# N1ql taking long time to execute

Tags: sql++

```
SELECT a.*, META(a).id FROM `pricing_qa_2` AS a
WHERE a.dtype = "qqcfxspd"  AND  1 = 1
ORDER BY LOWER(a.sch_name) ASC, a.aud_info.ts DESC  OFFSET 0 limit 24
```

Above query is taking long time to execute can you suggest apt index for this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Index and query combinations should have used Index Order avoided sort and extra fetch due to sort. Checkout EXPLAIN.

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON pricing_qa_2(LOWER(sch_name), aud_info.ts DESC) WHERE dtype = "qqcfxspd";

SELECT a.*, META(a).id 
FROM  `pricing_qa_2`  AS a 
WHERE a.dtype = "qqcfxspd" AND LOWER(sch_name) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY LOWER(sch_name) ASC, aud_info.ts DESC 
OFFSET 0 
LIMIT 24;
```

OR

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON pricing_qa_2(dtype, LOWER(sch_name), aud_info.ts DESC);

SELECT a.*, META(a).id 
FROM  `pricing_qa_2`  AS a 
WHERE a.dtype = "qqcfxspd" 
ORDER BY LOWER(sch_name) ASC, aud_info.ts DESC 
OFFSET 0 
LIMIT 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is an index on `a.dtype`:

```
CREATE INDEX dtype_idx ON pricing_qa_2(dtype)
```

I don't understand why you have a `1 = 1` clause in your query, but you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestion Johan and vsr helped a lot.
After creating below index and making small change in query I am able to get result in milliseconds.

```
REATE INDEX ix1 ON pricing_qa_2(LOWER(sch_name), aud_info.ts DESC) WHERE dtype = "qqcfxspd";

SELECT *, META().id FROM `pricing_qa_2` 
WHERE dtype = "qqcfxspd"  AND lower(sch_name) is not missing and aud_info.ts is not missing 
ORDER BY LOWER(ch_name) , aud_info.ts DESC  OFFSET 0 limit 24
```